# My webservice works with soapclient.com but not with soapsonar software:

Tags: web-services, rebol

I have put a webservice I found here http://www.rebolforces.com/zine/rzine-1-02/#sect6.
on my own website.

I tested http://reboltutorial.com/discordian.wsdl with
http://www.soapclient.com/soaptest.html

it did work as I got this answer

> Sweetmorn, Discord 48, Year of Our
>   Lady of Discord 3176

But doing the same thing with soapsonar gives me this response instead:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://reboltutorial.com/cgi-bin/discordian.cgi">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

Is soapsonar buggy or did I mischief something ?

Update seems giving same result with SoapUI:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Sun, 02 May 2010 17:33:54 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: http://reboltutorial.com/cgi-bin/discordian.cgi
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 210
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
X-Pad: avoid browser bug

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://reboltutorial.com/cgi-bin/discordian.cgi">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Apparently your problem is that you are a rebol without a cause.

Answer (score 1):

soapsonar is pretty clearly not sending the URL you expect to the rebol website. Unless it has an option to show you a wire trace, I'd ignore it, and stick with tools that work. SoapUi is a common alternative.

Comment: I have created a new WSDL with Visual Studio and now it works with SoapSonar but not with Visual Studio:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757695/webservice-works-with-soapsonar-but-not-with-visual-studio-winform